# Selecting cell in 1 Collection View to change second Collection View properties (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, collectionview

I’ve set up 2 Collection Views in Xcode - one holds empty cells with background colours and the other holds a collection of images.

When I select a cell in the first collection view I want to change all the background colours in the second Collection View to match the background colour of the cell I’ve selected.

The problem I’ve got is that only the cell with the matching index path changes in the second Collection View ie if I select the 3rd colour, the 3rd image changes.

How do I make it so that all the cells in the second Collection View change colour? I know it’s something to do with the index path but can’t figure out how to get round it.

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var colourView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var iconView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var height: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
   
    
    let colours = [
            UIColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.31, blue: 0.41, alpha: 1.00),
            UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.45, blue: 0.23, alpha: 1.00),
            UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.89, blue: 0.49, alpha: 1.00),
            UIColor(red: 0.73, green: 0.72, blue: 0.42, alpha: 1.00),
            UIColor(red: 0.01, green: 0.44, blue: 0.61, alpha: 1.00),
            UIColor(red: 0.56, green: 0.89, blue: 0.90, alpha: 1.00),
            UIColor(red: 0.84, green: 0.84, blue: 0.84, alpha: 1.00),
   
  ]
       
       
    
       
    let images = [UIImage(named: "home"), UIImage(named: "work"), UIImage(named: "key"), UIImage(named: "supermarket"), UIImage(named: "restaurant"), UIImage(named: "tree") , UIImage(named: "parking"), UIImage(named: "rugby"), UIImage(named: "medicine"), UIImage(named: "mortar"), UIImage(named: "ticket"), UIImage(named: "star")]
    
    

      
       
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
   
        
         
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       }
       
     func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           if (collectionView == iconView){
            return self.images.count
           }
           
           
        return self.colours.count
       }
    
   
       
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       
    let width = view.frame.size.width
        
        if (collectionView == iconView){
           return CGSize(width: width * 0.2, height: width * 0.2)
        
            
        }
                
    return CGSize(width: width * 0.1, height: width * 0.1)
       
     
              }

    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        
        if (collectionView == iconView){
                     let cell2 = iconView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "iconcell", for: indexPath) as! IconCollectionViewCell
                     
                     cell2.iconimage.image = self.images[indexPath.item]
             
                     return cell2
            
           
            
                 }
            let colourcell = colourView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colourcell", for: indexPath) as! ColourCollectionViewCell
           colourcell.backgroundColor = colours[indexPath.row]
           
           
        
           
           return colourcell
       }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
                       let cell = colourView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ColourCollectionViewCell
        
                        let cell2 = iconView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! IconCollectionViewCell
        
   

                       if cell.isSelected {
                        cell2.iconimage.backgroundColor = cell.backgroundColor
                       }


           
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a lot to do to put a sample code, but basically what you have to know is: when you select the color, put it in a variable and reload the collection view which will change color. In the <collectionView cellForItemAt> (where you build the colletion view) put the cells to adopt that color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a var:

```
class ViewController:
  var newColor : UIColor?
```

Change this:

```
if cell.isSelected {
   cell2.iconimage.backgroundColor = cell.backgroundColor
}
```

for this:

```
 if cell.isSelected {
    newColor = cell.backgroundColor
    iconView.reloadData()
 }
```

in

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

put this

```
if newColor != nil { // maybe a better test here, if cell was selected
   cell2.iconimage.backgroundColor = newColor
}
```

before

```
 return cell2
```